# How do I start developing applications for Ubuntu on mobile devices?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I've come away a little confused on how to develop mobile apps for Ubuntu.

First of all, do developers need the Ubuntu operating system to develop for Ubuntu?

Is it possible to develop Ubuntu apps in Windows?

Also, PhoneGap was mentioned somewhere along the way. I'm guessing this is something which isn't implemented yet? Where can I find out more information?

I'm currently using PhoneGap to target Android and Windows Phone, so it would be great if I could target Ubuntu with PhoneGap too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll get all the information you need on the [Cordova Overview](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/cordova/overview/) page, including a full tutorial. PhoneGap or other development platforms other than Ubuntu are not supported at this point.

Comment: The link is answer is not working. could you update that.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 4):

I have created a small blog post about creating apps for Ubuntu Phone OS. Hope it is useful to someone: [Developing a simple app for Ubuntu Phone OS | Napster's Experiments with Freedom](http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/43810725175/developing-a-simple-app-for-ubuntu-phone-os)

Comment: Cheers, it's as simple and short as it can get, which is a great tutorial for those new to Ubuntu mobile development.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.