# Need more information about API for 'Ubuntu for Phones'

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start developing applications for Ubuntu mobile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235441/how-do-i-start-developing-applications-for-ubuntu-mobile)

I would like to develop a app on Ubuntu for Phones. I have already developed apps on iPhone and Android. Could you please suggest me how I can download and setup the mobile development environment for Ubuntu for Phones, and also I would like to know the API documentation.

Comment: That thing you are referencing to is called 'Ubuntu for Android'.

Comment: It is definitely not called 'Ubuntu for Android', he specifically mentions "go mobile" which points to the [Ubuntu for Phones site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) (a totally different thing). For some excellent information on Ubuntu for Phones see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it?lq=1).

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ or installed their SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about how to get the Ubuntu SDK preview and a tutorial showing how to write an app here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

The QML API docs are available here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/overview-ubuntu-sdk.html