# How can I make a HTML5 app for Ubuntu Mobile?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is there any tutorial? I made some apps in HTML5 but I don't know how to "compile" or transform this code to obtain an Ubuntu Mobile App.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd start by reading through here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235441/how-do-i-start-developing-applications-for-ubuntu-mobile?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking here http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 as a core Internet technology is an alternative to the native QML applications and do not integrate that well into Ubuntu. HTML5 apps could as I know also developed for the Ubuntu Desktop OS. The hint you are looking for is "Unity webapps".

Have a look at http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/.

Comment: Why did you downvote? If my answer is wrong it would be important to know for the thread owner!

Comment: That page links to reference documentation at http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/javascript/unity-web-api-reference.html which seems to be missing. :(